# Embbed Widget Affected By CSS

Tags: javascript, css, widget, wolframalpha

I want to add a Wolfram|Alpha widget to my blog. It works very well just my adding this line of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="WolframAlphaScripte030edc7f50db29c394d01f61bba0e75" src="//www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widget.jsp?id=e030edc7f50db29c394d01f61bba0e75"></script>
```

The problem is that the style of the widget changes because of the CSS of my blog.

I don't have access to the code of the widget!

**What it *should* look like**

[image]

**What it looks like on my blog**

[image]

**How can I embed the widget without changing its layout?**

Comment: Your code is interfering with widget code. You probably have some global element CSS code in your blog which is likely modifying widget's styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look at wolfram alpha's widget search page and inspected the search box. It was structured as a table. Maybe you can inspect the widget you're using and see what css is affecting it.